# Open a URL in the same port and in http and https protocol

Tags: apache, http, ssl, https, virtualhost

I am trying to have my site open in port 8080 and can be accessed both in http:// and https://

But I am only able to open the site using https://, and always get an Error 400 whenever I open it using http://

Here is my apache configuration:

```
Listen 8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs
    ServerName xyz.net:8080
    ServerAdmin email@xyz.net
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs
    ServerName xyz.net:8080
    ServerAdmin email@xyz.net
</VirtualHost>
```

- *servername and serveradmin changed to hide information*

Here is the error I get when accessing thru http://

```
Bad request!

Your browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 400
```

Is there a way I can have port 8080 be accessed both in http and https protocol?

Comment: No, you can serve only one protocol on one port

Comment: SO, is there a way whenever they accessed the http protocol, it will automatically redirect it to the https protocol? Can it be done thru Virtualhosts?

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL

Comment: based on the link, it is a redirection from port 80 going to port 443. Is there a way for http://....:8080 be redirected to https://....8080 ?

Comment: No I told you, you can't use the same port to serve two protocols, even if you want to redirect A you need to use B, not A again but with different protocol. also 8080 is very unconventional to use for HTTPS, consider default 443, it's where all browsers would try

Comment: Ok. Noted. Unfortunately, our network blocks port 80 and port 443

Comment: @OlegBogdanov how does apache determine if the port is https or http, in this example it is not unambiguous